# How rewrite query in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, orm

Please Help rewrite to Django ORM

```
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE REPLACE(T.field, '-', ' ') = REPLACE(VALUE,'-', ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow "https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/". you can use raw query for Django ORM.

Comment: sorry, but raw Query not need. Need only Django ORM (this is test task, but i dont execute him, i dont know how)

Comment: obs = Goods.objects\ # i try do some this:
        .annotate(data2=Func(
                    # F('data'),
                    F('data'),
                    Value("'-'"), Value("' '"),
                    function='replace',

                ))\
        .filter(
            Q(data__contains="Andrew") |
            Q(
                data2=Func(
                    F('data'),
                    Value("'-7'"), Value("' 7'"),
                    function='replace',
                ),
            ))